# What is _Map in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dictionary

error: Converting object to an encodable object failed: _Map len:1

I am getting this error.

I am getting this error when I try to convert a simple map into json object in flutter.

My Code:
`final Map a = {1: "hello"};`
`final b = jsonEncode(a);` --> This here gives the error mentioned above.
`print(b);`

Comment: try `final Map a = {"1": "hello"};` - keys have to be strings, not integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using jsonEncode, the key must be a string:

```
import 'dart:convert';
void main() {
  final Map a = {'1': "hello"};
  final b = jsonEncode(a); 
  print(b);
}
```